# Do not show hidden icons

Tags: nautilus, hidden-files

I see the hidden files in nautilus. I pressed ctrl + h but when I open the file manager again hidden files appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go: Edit-> Preferences-> Views tab, is show hidden and back-up files turned on?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I do not have Edit menu, but i have Files menu, then in preferences i have disabled the show hidden files . Thanks. Now is working fine

Comment: @user If this answer solved your problem, please [accept it](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1141/44179)